# Error while connect to RFID reader: The maximum baud rate for the device is 8190

Tags: c#, windows, rfid, baud-rate

Hi I have a USB RFID Reader/Writer with name "**Silicon labs CP210x**", I develop a windows app with C# in *Visual studio 2015* that could Read/Write on RFID Card, its worked fine...

I change my Windows on my notebook (prev Windows and new Windows are Windows 10) and install *Visual Studio 2017*...Now when I open solution and run application see this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred
>
> HResult=0x80131502
>
> Message=The maximum baud rate for the device is 8190.

While googling in this error, I see some guys say that the error related to *baudrate* of reader But the reader and my application work fine until I change Windows and it should not related to *baudrate* ...ِI think its dont related to driver because the driver work on prev windows fine...Does anyone have any experience in this error?

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this problem and it was **solved** by uninstalling Silicon Labs Windows 10 **Universal** drivers and installing the Silicon Labs Windows **7/8/8.1/10** drivers.

Answer (score 2):

This error has not been reported before.

Have you tried opening the port with a standalone PC serial terminal program like Teraterm or Realterm?  I have seen C# hardcoding DCDs for the serial ports that have caused issues previously.

Can you go to your Device Manager, open Ports, right-click on the CP210x port, bring up Properties, go under Details, and scroll down to Bus reported device description?  That should have the actual chip type listed, ie "CP2102N USB to UART Bridge Controller".

Also, it would be a good idea to update the driver as well. Windows Update should provide the latest driver, but you can compare your version to the version on the Silicon Labs website at https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers

Comment: god bless you! thank you!
in 2021 it works with universal driver as well, but the 2021 version (2017 version was wrong)